# How do I break out of an infinite loop in Golang

Tags: for-loop, go

I'm making a program in Go for guessing a random number. I'm having issues with a for loop.

1. I can't stop the for loop from continuously iterating.
2. How do i break out of the loop once a condition is satisfied.

   ```
   for loop == true {

   //fmt.Println("read number", i, "/n")
   if i == ans {
       fmt.Println("well done")
   }
   if i != ans {
       fmt.Println("Nope")
       fmt.Scan(i)
   }
   ```

Comment: make the var `loop` equal to false on some break condition

Comment: Solved the issue just had to fix the scan() func and the loop break conditions

Comment: Try using "os.exit(0)"  it will surely work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to `break` out of the loop:

```
for {
    fmt.Scan(i)
    if i == ans {
        fmt.Println("well done")
        break
    }
    if i != ans {
        fmt.Println("Nope")
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok cool but its still wont let me loop properly. It goes into the loop then prints out nope if i dont enter a value any ideas?

Comment: Then you're gonna need to be more specific. What is not as you expect it?

Comment: Scan is probably not behaving as you expect it to. Read [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scan) and check your errors.

Comment: and something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/40061275/121660 is usually a better way to read lines then Scan directly

Comment: Solved it it was a combination of an issue with Scan and the loop i used continue to re loop when needed

Comment: Add a `break` to the second `if` to stop the `for` loop continuously iterating?